# Weird behavior on reboot and shut down

Tags: linux, windows, shutdown, reboot

Ever since I bought my new machine I have this really weird behavior on reboot and shut down:

When I invoke a shut down, the system will shut down just fine, but the hardware stays on. I have to hold the power button 4 seconds to force that annoying hardware power off - every time I want to shut down the machine. After waiting for the system to halt first of course. If i don't do that, it will just stay on and not do anything since the system has halted. Very annoying! My first assumption had always been that just something is wrong with either the board or the PSU.

Well, here's the weird thing: When I request the system to reboot the system will reboot as expected, but now, once the system is going to send the signal for reboot, my machine actually turns completey off and will (after one second) turn on automagically again! I would expect that on a shut down, without the part where it turns on again of course. In contrast, I wouldn't think the hardware actually turns off completely on a reboot. At least I never experienced that with any of the machines I had.

This happened to me on every system I used on this machine, which would be Windows 7, Windows 8, Windows 8.1 and various Linux distributions.

To the specs: *random* consumer hardware I'd say, infested with UEFI BIOS, got a sufficient PSU, RAM ... Well, the machine runs just fine except when I try to shut it down or reboot.

**What's wrong?** Or rather: What could be the cause? (And obviously: How can I fix this?)

Comment: What are the machine's specs?

Comment: I would expect there to be a conflict that can be resololved by changing a BIOS setting such as ACHI. I have insufficient knowledge at this point to post a full solution, but it might help you get on the right track, or allow other users to get ideas to what could solve this issue.

Comment: It seems to be a problem with your motherboard i faced this issue several times